# MongoDB aggregate $match using dynamic field path

Tags: mongodb

I want to match documents in my pipeline based on whether the field to match is contained within an array that is within my documents.

Example document to match:

```
{
  'wishlist': ['123','456','789'],
  'productId': '123'
}
```

Example match aggregation:

```
{
   $match: {
        'productId': {$in: '$wishlist'}
   }
}
```

This isn't working - error is '$in needs an array' - but `'$wishlist'` is an array? so clearly the stage isn't picking up the path reference.

How would I get something like this to work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match the internal field of the document, you can use [$expr](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) expression operator, and I see that field has an array value then you have to use [$in](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) operator's aggregation syntax,

```
{
   $match: {
        $expr: { 
            $in: ["$productId", '$wishlist'] 
        }
   }
}
```